# Is there a significant difference between age and the prevalence of UTI?

Tags: statistical-significance

I really dont know how to calculate. All i want is to determine if there is significant difference on the data that i studied. Here are the figures:

```
Total population: 204
Total # of positive with UTI: 76
Table 1  Prevalence of UTI in relation to age
Age         Number Sampled             Number Positive(%)
15-20          52                           26(50%)
21-25          42                           15(35.7%)
26-30          46                           12(26%)
31-35          36                           14(38.8%)
36-40          28                            9(32.1)
```

How can I determine if there is a significant difference between age and the prevalence of UTI? Help please!

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking. Do you want to know whether or not age is related to prevalence of UTI?

Comment: yes sir, that is what i want to know

Answer (score -1):

Although the frequency is highest in the lowest age bracket and starts decreasing, it starts increasing again after age 30.  Certainly, there is no linear trend but a quadratic trend is possible.  You may be able to fit some sort of polynomial trend and then determine whether or not it appears to be a good fit.

Comment: This sounds like data snooping.  Why not recommend a test that would be prescribed based on the study question alone, *before the data were obtained*?  A simple $\chi^2$ test would work fine.